# Run through geocoder on two locations entered

Tags: iphone, location, geocoding

I am developing an iPhone app that takes in two locations from the user. I want to perform two iterations of geocode but my code runs the first geocode but never does the second.

I am not using a for loop for now, just want to have the geocode run twice and print the coordinates to two different UILabels.

What am I missing?

```
- (IBAction)fetchCoordinates:(id)sender {
if (!self.geocoder) {
    self.geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
}

NSString *address1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.yourLocation.text];
NSString *address2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.theirLocation.text];

[self.geocoder geocodeAddressString:address1 completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if ([placemarks count] > 0) {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;

    self.coordinatesLabel1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];
    }
}];

[self.geocoder geocodeAddressString:address2 completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if ([placemarks count] > 0) {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;

    self.coordinatesLabel2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];
    }
}];

}

@end
```

Comment: does any error get passed back in the NSError parameters of the completion handler?

Comment: No, no errors are given. I have an activity indicator that begins spinning when I press the button. The first coordinate set is delivered but the second is not. The activity indicator continues to spin until I close the simulator.

Comment: Just some additional info on this. I see NSError logs if I simply turn off the internet connection on my laptop (I see the 'no internet connection' error), so I know it is logging OK. I see no errors returned after the first set of coordinates is returned. The activity indicator simply keeps spinning and the second set of coordinates never gets returned. The next thing I am going to try is a tcpdump on my wireless interface to see what gets sent to geocode sites for resolution.

Comment: It looks from the tcpdump that I only see the one request and response, so I am assuming this is for the first location.

Comment: did you ever get this solved, Dan?

Comment: No. I ended up using the Google geocoding mechanism instead of Apple's and I got it working that way. Different approach that gets to the same goal.